# How to make toggle button in flutter pop out a calendar and time

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, togglebutton

I've want to create two toggle buttons that will display an option to choose the date and time from the calendar but the calendar doesn't pop out. I've tried to look for some answers but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Code:

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 400, 256, 0),
            child: ToggleButtons(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
                Icon(Icons.wifi),
                Icon(Icons.flash_on),
              ],
              isSelected: _isSelected,
            ),
          ),
```

List

```
 List<bool> _isSelected = [false, true, false];
```

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: Share your code

Comment: added code @JahidulIslam

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `CupertinoSwitch` inside a `ListTile`. Then `onTap` open a `CupertinoDatePicker` or whichtever your choice of calendar picker. For Example:

```
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Time',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                        activeColor: Color(0xff59a3fd),
                        value: globals.isEnable //your switch value here
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                            globals.isEnable = value;
                          });
                          
                        },
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                         
                          //Open your calender here
                          showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return _buildBottomPicker(
                                  CupertinoDatePicker(
                                   mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                   initialDateTime: date,
                                   onDateTimeChanged: (DateTimeaddSelectedDate){                                     
                                      setState(() {
                                        this.newDateTime = addSelectedDate;
                                           date = newDateTime;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );                           
                          },
                        )
```